# How can I determine the Cartesian equation of a straight line in OpenCV with Python?

Tags: opencv

I used Canny edge detection in an image to identify a line in the image. Now, I was curious about whether is there a way we can use to determine the equation of straight line in open cv?

Comment: `cv2.HoughLinesP` detects line and returns the end points.

Comment: But how would you form the equation of a line? I know you can do manually, but how to do so with an OpenCV function?